# Using @Hidden or passing through BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5

I have a small question about the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17013690/2715331) answer from a stackoverflow question.

There seem to be 2 ways to pass parameters through a `@BeginForm()` to a Controller.

Using a Hidden field:

```
@Html.Hidden("clubid", ViewBag.Club.id)
```

Using the BeginForm:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("action", "controller",
                       new { clubid = @Viewbag.Club.id }, FormMethod.Post, null)
```

My question is: what is/are the main difference(s) between the 2?
Should one be used in a specific situation over the other?
Does one have limitations over the other?

Comment: Have you looked at [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29) about this function call?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman I have but i'm not the brightest crayon in the box.